# Eigenvalues of the product of symmetric and positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ , $B$ be two real symmetric matrices and $A$ is positive definite. Then show that $AB$ has real eigenvalues.

Symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues and product of two symmetric matrices need not be symmetric. How can the positive definiteness of $A$ be used here to show that the eigenvalues of $AB$ are real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A = S^t S.$ Then $AB = S^t S B.$ The eigenvalues of $AB$ are thus the same as those of $S^tBS,$ which is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: I'm probably being dense here, but how did you go from $S^t S B$ to $S^t B S$?

Comment: @Bungo by typing too fast, it's $SBS^t.$

Comment: @IgorRivin What kind of a matrix is S and can every positive definite matrix be written in that form ?

Comment: @user766787 Nonsingular, and yes (exercise).

Comment: @IgorRivin Okay, I will try to prove that. Thank you so much.