# Maximal eigenvalue of $AB^{-1}$ when matrices $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and $A \preceq B$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A $ and $ B $ be symmetric matrices. Can we say something about the eigenvalues of the matrix product $AB$ when $A \preceq B$ in the sense that $ A-B $ is positive semidefinite? Can we conclude maybe that $$ \lambda_{\max}(AB) \leq 1 $$

where $ \lambda_{\max} $ is the largest eigenvalue? If so, how?

We don't assume that $ A $ and $ B $ commute. In this case, they should be simultaneously diagonalizable since they are both symmetric.

Correction of what I wrote: $ A\leqslant B $ means $ B-A $ is semi-definite positive. And I also made an error of what I'm searching: I want to know if there is result on $ \lambda_{\max}(B^{-1}A) $, e.g. $\lambda_{\max}(B^{-1}A) \leq 1 $ (we assume that $ B $ and $ A $ are invertible)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573583/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-2-symmetric-matrices)

Comment: Remember that real numbers are symmetric matrices in 1D equal to their (only) eigenvalue. And scalar matrices, multiples of $I$, behave the same way in any dimension. So if something isn't true for real numbers it can't be true for symmetric matrices. And why would a product of two real numbers be less than $1$ if all you know about them is that one is less than the other?

Comment: I don't understand how $A \preceq B$ is equivalent to $ A-B \succeq 0$.

Comment: Are you sure that $AB$ has real eigenvalues?

Comment: If $0\preceq A\preceq B$, then $\lambda_\max(AB)\leq \lambda_\max(A)\lambda_\max(B)$ with equality for example if $A=B$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry, that was too quick. It is true if one of the factors is positive semi-definite, and the proof can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118968/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-symmetric-and-positive-definite-matrices.

Comment: Correction of my question: $ A\leq B \Leftrightarrow B-A $ is semi-definite positive

Comment: there are a lot of problems here.  In addition to twice mentioned issue that question doesn't make sense for non PSD $B$ (i.e. PD since invertible), the title uses $B^{-1}$ and the text seems to not.  If $B$ is PD and the title is the actual question then this can be done via congruence.

Comment: @user8675309 Can you please elaborate more on how to use congruence to prove maximum eigenvalue of $AB^{-1}$ is bounded by 1?